# Firestore => variable not updating with latest value from FireStore Database inside .onSnapShot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

#### Want I want to achieve is:

- I want to get all new SMS after a specific Date.

I'm developing an SMS based chat application.
I have many `ChatRooms` and each `ChatRoom` has many `messages`.

Every time I click on a chat-room I'm saving a timestamp string on FireStore Database (as a last time I visited that chat-room)

If a new message comes in after that, I want to show a number notification (just like Whatsapp does for example).

[image: Here's an example from my own app]

#### What/Where is the Bug:

- A new SMS comes in from a client
- Loop over all `ChatRooms` looking for new incoming SMS
- Grab (put into an array) the ones that are newer (greater than) the last-time I visited that chat-room.
- Update the Firestore database with the new incoming SMS.
- Show notification to the end-user.

The second time I click on that chat-room it updates the timestamp on the database, but my code keeps getting the previous time I visited.

Here's the database screenshot:

[image: firestore screenshot]

See on my debugger the red lines show the timestamp doesn't match at all ( it never updates)

[image]

And the code:

```
unread_messages = currentUser => {
    // console.log("is this firing");
    const chatRoomsQuery = this.db.collection("ChatRooms");
    const clientsQuery = this.db.collection("Clients_development");
    let data = [];

    // put a listener on every chatRoom
    let unsubscribe2 = chatRoomsQuery.onSnapshot(messages => {
      messages.docs.forEach(message => {
        console.log("message.data().lastVisited", message.data().lastVisited);
        let phoneId = message.id;
        // console.log("phoneId: ", phoneId);
        //! get messages sent ONLY by clients NOT the ones the agent sent to users
        let unsubscribe = this.db
          .collection("ChatRooms")
          .doc(phoneId)
          .collection("messages")
          .where("from", "==", phoneId)
          .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            // ! LOOP OVER ALL INCOMING SMS FOR EVERY CLIENT
            querySnapshot.forEach(sms => {
              const smsMsg = new Date(sms.data().timestamp);
              const lastVisit = new Date(message.data().lastVisited);
              // update it
              if (smsMsg.getTime() > lastVisit.getTime()) {
                data.push(sms.data());
                console.log("this one:", sms.data());
                clientsQuery
                  .where("phone", "==", sms.data().from)
                  .get()
                  .then(querySnapshot => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                      this.db
                        .collection("Clients_development")
                        .doc(doc.id)
                        .update({
                          unread_messages: Array.from(new Set(data))
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                          console.log("updated");
                          data = [];
                        })
                        .catch(e => console.log(e));
                    });
                  })
                  .catch(e => console.log(e));
              }
              // data = [];
            });
          });
        return () => unsubscribe();
      });
    });
    return () => unsubscribe2();
  };
```

[image: An a picture of the code]

## Why is the lastVisited var NOT updating inside the .OnSnapShot ???

Also, after days of trying to figure this out, this code now leads me to infinite loop:

```
unread_messages = () => {
    const chatRoomsQuery = this.db.collection("ChatRooms");
    const messagesQuery = this.db.collection("ChatRooms");
    let newMessages = [];

    chatRoomsQuery.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(chatRoom => {
        const id = chatRoom.id;
        console.log("current customer id: ", id);

        messagesQuery
          .doc(id)
          .collection("messages")
          .onSnapshot(query => {
            query.forEach(message => {
              console.log(
                "current query message: ",
                message.data().customer_response
              );
              newMessages.push(message.data());
            });

            // we're mapping over all SMS messages
            newMessages.forEach(message => {
              console.log("current message: ", message);
              // here you can run the transaction
              return this.db.runTransaction(transaction => {
                const currRef = this.db
                  .collection("ChatRooms")
                  .doc(message.from);

                return transaction
                  .get(currRef)
                  .then(doc => {
                    if (!doc.exists) {
                      return;
                    }
                    // update it
                    if (
                      new Date(message.timestamp).getTime() >
                      new Date(doc.data().lastVisited)
                    ) {
                      transaction.update(currRef, {
                        unread_messages: Array.from(
                          new Set([message.customer_response])
                        )
                      });
                    }
                  })
                  .then(function() {
                    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
                    newMessages = [];
                  })
                  .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
                  });
              });
            });
          });
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: I was trying to figure it out, but it seems I am not able... :( . Anyway, isn't it more effective if you assign this `lastVisit` before 2nd `onSnapshot`? You are doing the same operation in every forEach loop. Can you add code where you do update of the field?

Comment: Is this behavior the same no matter how many time you test it? Have you tried to add more items to be processed?